# Big QPixmaps crashes with OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, qgraphicsview

I'm programming a QGraphicsView that has a lot of images. But when I display a JPEG with resolution 8528 x 1128 px (a panorama image), the QGraphicsPixmapItem does not render. It just displays a black square. Images of "normal" size renders good. I have not tried to find the "magick limit" for what sizes the problem occures on.

**On my laptop with Ubuntu 10.10 x64 it also chrashes the graphics card driver and restarts the Gnome session!**

Everything works fine if I disable OpenGL.

Why? Are there anything I can do?

I've found another having a very similar problem: http://www.qtforum.org/article/34238/really-strange-problem-with-qgraphicsview-and-opengl.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure this returns something greater than 8528 on your OpenGL implementation:

```
GLint texSize;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &texSize);
```

If it doesn't you're going to have to resort to some sort of tiled rendering system so you can fit all your image data in textures smaller than the maximum size.

Comment: Just to reinforce this point - you're far exceeding the safe limits for a GL texture, as well as using a non-square, non-power-of-two dimension. All these factors reduce the hardware and GL drivers you're likely to work on. The good news is, since you're already using a QGraphicsView, splitting your huge image into pieces (on the CPU), and creating separate graphics items for each tile, should be easy.